# Shift times in org agenda by minutes or hours instead of days

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

In an org-mode agenda, how can I shift the time of an item by minutes or hours?

<kbd>Shift - Right Arrow</kbd> shifts by one day, but I want to shift by hours or minutes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The command you are calling with your binding is
`org-agenda-do-date-later`.  As of my `org` version,
`describe-function` tells me that there is no docstring for that
function:

> `(org-agenda-do-date-later ARG)`
>
> Not documented.

However, it *does* take an argument.

If you follow the link to the source code for that function, it
indicates that, if you pass a prefix argument to that command, it
will call `org-agenda-date-later-hours`.  If you pass it two
prefixes, it will call `org-agenda-date-later-minutes`.

Long story short:

- To delay an item by a day, use <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>right arrow</kbd>
- To delay an item by an hour, use <kbd>C-u</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>right arrow</kbd>
- To delay an item by 5 minutes, use <kbd>C-u</kbd><kbd>C-u</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>right arrow</kbd>

  - The 5 comes from the variable `org-time-stamp-rounding-minutes`.

Comment: Just a tip for Spacemacs users - use SPC u instead of C-u.